# how to make image appear when player is dead in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to  make an image pop up when the player has died or crashed but i do not know how to do it, i'm trying to make a game in unity using c#
 but i have made a code that will tell show the user an image before they start (tap to start image) and all i want to do is display another one that tell to user to start again 
does the code have to be similar to this or do i have to start from scratch?

```
public class StartScreenScript : MonoBehaviour {

    static bool sawOnce = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        if(!sawOnce) {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = true;
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        }

        sawOnce = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Time.timeScale==0 && (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) ) {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().enabled = false;

        }
    }
}
```

this code show the an image telling the user to tap the screen and the image then goes away until the user closes the game then comes back on however i want to display a "you are dead image" every time the player dies can someone please help me

p.s this is for a 2d game

Answer (score 0):

Well one way to do it would be using Unity3D's [GUI.DrawTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUI.DrawTexture.html) that given a texture draws it at a given position. Here is a sample call to the method.

```
GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(leftAnchor, topAnchor, textureWidth, textureHeight), textureSource);
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is my approach and it works in most cases:**

- Create a `GameObject` that will work as a dead screen. Apply a sprite
  or whatever telling the user to click to restart.
- Add the previous `GameObject` to the `PlayerController` so he can
  instantiate it.
- When the player is dead call `PlayerController.ShowDeadScreen()`
- When the user clicks inside DeadScreen `GameObject` it will call your
  `PlayerController.PlayAgain` function and destroy itself. So you must handle everything
  the game need to be restarted.

#### PlayerController example code

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject deadScreen;

    void Start() { }

    void Update() { }

    public void ShowDeadScreen()
    {
        // show DeadScreen GameObject on the center of the screen
        GameObject go = Instantiate(deadScreen, new Vector(0, 0, 0), Quaternation.Identity) as GameObject;
        go.playerController = this;
    }

    public void PlayAgain()
    {
        // handle game restart
    }

}
```

#### DeadScreen example code

```
public class DeadScreen : MonoBehaviour {

    public PlayerController playerController;

    void Start() { }

    void Update() { }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        // when user clicks inside this GameObject start the game again
        playerController.PlayAgain();
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }

}
```